# Is this a CORS request?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, cors

I'm getting a CORS error with my WebAPI project but it's confusing me a little

I'm doing an jquery ajax post from my website `http://local.mysite.com` to my web api site `http://api.local.mysite.com/upload`

Here's my error

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://api.local.mysite.com/upload. 
Origin http://local.mysite.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

I (probably mistakenly) thought it would be ok to host my API under an `api.` prefix and that would count as the same domain.  Should be getting a CORS error in this situation?

Looks like support has been added for it [here](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=CORS%20support%20for%20ASP.NET%20Web%20API&referringTitle=Specs) which should make it easy to make work.

p.s The reason for the `.local` is because I have multiple test sites `.dev` `.main` etc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per same origin policy, http://local.mysite.com and http://api.local.mysite.com are different origins. Please check the section "Origin determination rules" in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy. BTW, cookies do work with the domain sub-domain situation that you have and may be that is what made you think that this will not be a problem for jQuery AJAX.